# Where should I put the Java Swing API method calls?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've just started to learn Java Graphical Programming. And I have a question. Where should I put the Swing APIs (such at `setSize`, `setLocation`, `setTitle`, etc)?

In the main method or in the constructor? Some tutorials put them inside the constructor of the class that extends the JFrame, but some others put them inside the main method. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: *"Where should I put the Swing APIs (such at setSize, setLocation, setTitle, etc)? In the main method or in the constructor? Some tutorials put them inside the constructor of the class that extends the JFrame"* 1) Don't use `setSize(..)` - instead call `pack()` once all components are added. The former is a guess, the latter is the minimum size needed to display the components. 2) Don't call `setLocation(..)` but instead call `setLocationByPlatform(true)` before the frame is set visible. 3) Don't call `setTitle(..)`, but pass the title in the frame constructor. 4) And don't extend `JFrame` ..

Comment: (4 continued) ..just use an instance of a plain `JFrame`. I've never seen a good case for extending frame & I doubt one exists here.

Comment: There's no "right" answer.  In some cases, you want to have a self defined, re-usable object which performs some self configuration, sometimes you don't.  In some cases, it might be better to consider a factory style approach instead, which would give you the best of both worlds